# Sealing rusted spots for safety

Tags: seal, rust

I have an old enamel wash basin that I’d like to use as a photography prop. It has some rusty spots, which actually just lend character so I don’t mind them. But I want to make sure it is safe for the little ones. Is there a way to seal it off nicely?  Thank In advance for your advice!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Rust is not dangerous, so ... ?

Comment: sealant may produce undesirable light reflections

Comment: Rust is a vitamin, it [makes blood red](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=2419) and you'll die without it.

Answer (score 1):

If you step on a dirty rusty nail in a barn, the problem is the puncture wound and the dirt, not the rust.  Rust is just oxidized iron and not especially dangerous on contact. 
As long as it's clean with no sharp edges, burrs, etc., there is no need to seal it for safety.

Sealing it may slow the rust from spreading though.  Clear nail polish would probably work as well as anything.